# Add delay to recursive function without modifying it

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say function fib():

```
function fib(n) {
  if (n < 2){
    return n
  }
  return fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
}
```

Now, let's say I want to display each step of this recursive function in a document.write, and progressively add the result of each iteration with a delay of 1000ms between steps. Can I do it without modifying the original function by perhaps having another function, passing this one as the argument, creating the output mechanism, and since it also returns a function, recursively add the delay?

Comment: Your current function does not ever print anything, its only output (ultimate return value of a single external call to `fib`) is the final result of that initial call, so no, I don't think it's possible without modifying `fib`. Are you permitted to add a `console.log` in there?

Comment: You definitely *can't* use `document.write` here, because `document.write` will *clear the existing document* if the document has already loaded. (Best to never use `document.write`, use a more modern method of DOM manipulation, like `createElement` etc)

Comment: You would need a sleep(1000) or something similar.

Comment: No, you can't, because Javascript is strictly evaluated. If you call `fib` it will run to completion, i.e. until the base case is reached

Comment: We could output the result without modifying it by simply doing document.write(fib(10)); Or creating a new function, write(fn){ document.write(fn); } and calling it like write(fib(n)); Is there somethng we could add inside write() that adds the delay between steps for the recursive fib?

Comment: @reify, this is what I suspected. Guess I need to modify it :)

Comment: No, unless you can modify the current `fib`, it's impossible to intercept its internal recursive calls. If you're permitted to add a `console.log` to it, though, it *would* be possible.

Comment: the problem is the named function. even if you use another function with an assigned same name, the inside closure over the name is static.

Comment: I see that I can intercept a function call, if I intercept fib(n), it should be intercepted by its own recursive calls, right?

https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2014-09-09-javascript-function-call-interception.html

I will try it.

Comment: No, you can't do that. You could definitely "tap" into `fib` in order to add some `console.log`, however if you can't modify the original `fib` that means it's still working as `synchronous` function: adding the delay means that each `fib` call would be `async`: therefore you can't have a the sum `fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)`, since such operation is `sync`.
If the constraint is that you cannot modify the original `fib` but you can only tap into it, you can't add a timeout given the code you provided.

Comment: Said that, you can definitely tap into the function and schedule a `console.log` every 1000ms: *however* that means that the function is finished already to be executed, it's just the `console.log` for each step that is delayed. And I don't think that's what you want.

Comment: @NinaScholz Actually it works for a named function declaration, only named function expressions close over their identifier in a local scope.

Comment: @ZER0 You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 4):

No, but writing it as a *generator* instead would give you a useful interface  to implement something like that

```js
function*fib() {
  for (let a = 1, b = 1, c = 0;; c = a+b, a = b, b = c) yield a;
}
const sleep = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
const gen = fib();

// then, use it step by step

console.log(gen.next().value); 
console.log(gen.next().value); 

// OR with a delay inbetween  
 
async function slowly() {
  for (let v of gen) {
    console.log(v);
    await sleep(1000);
  }
}
slowly();
```

Comment: You should wrap `gen.next()` into a loop and add time delay to demonstrate how it helps.

Comment: @klenium Good idea

Comment: Your generator function is odd. I tried it with a recursive generator  `function* fib(n) {if (n < 2){return n} const x = yield* fib(n - 1); const y = yield* fib (n - 2); return x + y;}`, but then it is strictly evaluated again. Dunno how to avoid exhausting the generator immediately.

Comment: @reify That's because in both branches your generator immediately `return`s

Comment: I see, this works `function* fib(n) {if (n < 2){yield n; return} const x = yield* fib(n - 1); const y = yield* fib (n - 2); return x + y;}`

Answer (score 1):

Because your original function is synchronous, without modifying you cannot really call it as if it were asynchronous.

JavaScript allows you to overwrite a symbol like your function, `fib`. This allows you to redefine it whatever you just want. Maybe you could make it asynchronous with dynamically added behavior, I don't know, but that would be too complicated.

However, you said "I want to display each step of this recursive function ... with a delay of 1000 ms between steps". You can easily do this, because you can call `fib` synchronously, but print the results asynchronously! Example:

```js
function fib(n) {
  if (n < 2){
    return n
  }
  return fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
}

var queue = [];
var depth = 0;
var manageCall = function(fn){
    return function() {
        ++depth;
        let result = fn.apply(this, arguments);
        --depth;
        queue.push(" ".repeat(depth)+fn.name+"("+arguments[0]+") = "+result);
        return result;
    };
};
var fib = manageCall(fib);
fib(8);
var printDelayed = function() {
    if (queue.length != 0) {
        console.info(queue.pop());
        setTimeout(printDelayed, 1000);
    }
}
printDelayed();
```

`fib` is unchanged, but can follow how the recursion were executed.

Comment:  for ES5 (except that one `let`)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so ... You *probably* actually can do this, but you're gonna have to get really creative.  This is extremely non-performant code, and likely would need some tweaks to actually function, but you could conceivably take this just a bit further to get what you're after.

**What we're doing**

So, we're going to be ripping out the guts of a defined function that's passed to our mangler function `waitAndPrintFunc`. That function will output the function as a string, and then use it to rebuild a Frankenstein function that's executed via `eval`.

**PLEASE NOTE:** Don't *EVER* use this in a production environment.  This code is a living abomination just to prove that something like this could be done.

```
//global
let indexCounter = 0;

const waitAndPrintFunc = (func) => {
    let wholeFunc = func.toString();
    const funcName = wholeFunc.slice(8, wholeFunc.indexOf('(')).replace(' ', '');
    let funcBody = wholeFunc.slice(wholeFunc.indexOf('{') + 1, wholeFunc.lastIndexOf('}'));
    const returnIndex = funcBody.indexOf(`return ${funcName}`);
    const meatyPart = funcBody.slice(returnIndex + 7);
  wholeFunc = wholeFunc.split('');
  funcBody = funcBody.split('');

    funcBody.splice(
        returnIndex,
        funcBody.length - returnIndex,
        `document.querySelector('.output').appendChild("step \${indexCounter++}: \${eval(meatyPart)}"); setTimeout(() => {${meatyPart}}, 1000);`
    );
    wholeFunc.splice(0, 9 + funcName.length, 'const MyRiggedFunction = ');
  wholeFunc.splice(wholeFunc.indexOf(')') + 1, 0, ' => ');

    wholeFunc.splice(wholeFunc.indexOf('{') + 1, wholeFunc.lastIndexOf('}'), ...funcBody);
  console.log(wholeFunc.join(''))
    eval(`${wholeFunc.join('')} ; MyRiggedFunction(1)`);
};

function fib(n) {
    if (n < 2) {
        return n;
    }
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}

waitAndPrintFunc(fib);
```

Comment: Wow, I cringed at "string" and gasped at "eval", awesome!

Comment: Promising but currently gives a `SyntaxError`

Answer (score 0):

> I see that I can intercept a function call, if I intercept fib(n), it should be intercepted by its own recursive calls, right? https://bytes.babbel.com/en/articles/2014-09-09-javascript-function-call-interception.html I will try it

No, you can't do that.

You could definitely "tap" into `fib` in order to add some `console.log`:

```
// original function
function fib(n) {
  if (n < 2){
    return n
  }
  return fib(n - 1) + fib (n - 2)
}

// rebind the var `fib` to a wrapper to the original `fib`
var fib = ((orig) => (n) => {
    console.log('tap:', n);
    return orig(n)
  }
)(fib);

console.log("result:", fib(7));
```

However if the prerequisite is that you **cannot** modify the original `fib` that means it's still working as *synchronous* function: adding the delay means that `fib` becomes *asynchronous*.
But the return value of `fib` itself, since it's recursive, is using an addition operator (`fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)`), and therefore is expecting an immediate value, not something delayed.

If the constraint is that you cannot modify the original `fib` but you can only tap into it, you can't add a timeout given the code you provided.

Said that, you can definitely tap into the function and schedule a `console.log` every 1000ms: however that means that the function is finished already to be executed, it's just the `console.log` for each step that is delayed.

And I don't think that's what you want.